# window.event.srcElement could not work in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript

this is my code.

```
function postbackOnCheck() {
    var o = window.event.srcElement;

    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') - 1) 
    {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

and i done few research. Found that window.event.srcElement could not use in firefox. So i change the coding into..

```
function postbackOnCheck() {
    var o = window.event.srcElement || e.target;

    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') - 1) 
    {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

but yet still not working. hope anyone could help me.

Comment: You're attempting to use `e.target` but `e` does not exist. Can you show the code that calls `postbackOnCheck`?

Comment: Can you please provide more details. On what context that you are writing this function?

Answer (score 4):

`window.event` does not exist in Firefox, so it will throw an error if you try to access `window.event.srcElement`. Even if it worked, you never defined `e` anywhere, so `e.target` will error as well.

In W3C-compatible browsers, the event object is passed as first argument to the event handler. In IE, it is accessible via `window.event`.
Hence, to get a reference to the even object, we have to do:

```
function eventHandler(event) {
    // if `event` is not defined, we fall back to `window.event`
    event = event || window.event;
}
```

To get a reference to the element that triggered the event, we have to access `event.target` in W3C-compatible browsers and `event.srcElement` in IE:

```
// if `event.target` is not defined, we fall back to `event.srcElement`
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

---

A great source to learn about event handling and the browser differences is [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).